# Select rows from two tables where one field must not be duplicate

Tags: mysql

i have two tables:

table_A:
**id | file**

table_B:
**id | docs_id | approved | public | publish_time | version**

Now, docs_id of the table_B is the id of table_A.

I want to get the id and file of the last 20 entries (ordered descending by publish_time).
My problem is, that there are several rows in the table_B where the only thing different (besides publish_time) is the version. so i only want to get the latest version.

```
SELECT d.* FROM docs d LEFT JOIN doc_versions dv ON d.id = dv.docs_id WHERE dv.approved='1' AND dv.public='1' ORDER BY publish_time DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

How could i improve this query, so i dont get duplicates? Distinct doesnt work, because the rows aren't exactly the same, because of the version field (since i dont count seconds in my publish_time timestamp, it is possible that there is a row where publish_time is equal to another row but the versions differ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your query is not returning anything from the version, so you can do:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM docs d LEFT JOIN
     doc_versions dv
     ON d.id = dv.docs_id
WHERE dv.approved='1' AND dv.public='1'
group by d.doc_id
ORDER BY max(publish_time) DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

The only issue appears to be the `order by` clause.  If the most recent version has the most recent publish_time, then this will have the right ordering (and hence selection).